# Laravel localhost:8000 not working for chrome or safari but it is for firefox on school network

Tags: laravel, networking

I am on school network and for some reason when I run any Laravel Project I have via PHP artisan serve I go to localhost:8000(I've tried variations and including the http//:localhost:8000 and others)and 
I get 
'safari can't connect to server..localhost' on safari
and chrome 
'this site can't be reached'
But on firefox it works just fine which is weird, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Your school probably uses proxy settings and Chrome / Safari are not properly configured.

Comment: refresh cleaning the cache